# RTSP over SSL (RTSPS)

Tags: ssl, video-streaming, rtsp, wowza, android-video-player

We have a video streaming (video on demand) server implemented using wowza streaming engine. Clients (android application, web browser) access the stream using RTMP (web browser) and RTSP (android application). As we have requirement that the streaming should be over SSL, as web browser's player (jw player) supports RTMPS, I have configured wowza to support RTMPS and tested the functionality. But we also need to support RTSP over SSL (RTSPS). I have read that wowza doesn't support RTSPS (ref: https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?34002-RTP-RTSP-over-SSL). Then we need to terminate the SSL on ELB itself(our video streaming server is behind an ELB).

We are using ffmpeg player in android player. Under this [link](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html) there is nothing mentioned regarding RTSPS or RTSP over SSL. Just I am wondering whether such a protocol exists ?. If so, is there any android player or any other player I can use for testing RTSPS ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Please go through the below link to configure your server to accept secured connection

[https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-get-ssl-certificates-from-the-streamlock-service#rtmpsPlayback][1]

2. Cross compile your ffmpeg to support openssl library.
3. Push your video stream to wowza using "rtsps"

> eg:
>
> > ffmpeg -re -i  -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f rtsp
> >     rtsps://username:password@:443/live/myStream

Answer (score 0):

I was recommend place a LB infront of my Wowza for SSL offloading so you can load the m3u8 over SSL. I was also told you can do that quite easily using HA Proxy for example. It is explained how to accomplish this here for RTMP but the same can obviously done with HTTP:

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/457#issuecomment-250783255

Note, I have not tried this yet and I am unclear on exactly the proper use scenario. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hostport to enable Streaming RTP/RTSP over SSL

```
<HostPort>
            <Name>Default Secure Streaming</Name>
            <Type>Streaming</Type>
            <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
            <IpAddress>*</IpAddress>
            <Port>1937</Port>
            <HTTPIdent2Response></HTTPIdent2Response>
            <SSLConfig>    
                <KeyStorePath>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/conf/keystore.jks</KeyStorePath>
                <KeyStorePassword>somePassword</KeyStorePassword>
            </SSLConfig>
            ...
</HostPort>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can playback over RTSPS with Wowza Streaming Engine.

With your SSL certificate in place, try this to test playback using the sample file provided in [install-dir]/content/sample.mp4 and the provided **vod** application.

> ffplay rtsps://[your-wowza/cert-domain]:443/vod/mp4:sample.mp4

Comment: Lisa, Thanks for your quick reply.. Unfortunately it's not working. I got the error saying that "Creating Security Context Failed (0x80090304)". I'm sure that I have configured my certificates and VHost properly as rtmps streaming is working